# JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'innerHTML' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript

It's wired! There is an external JS file and I'm calling a function inside it from .aspx page which will get the selected content and identifies the `<Table>` tag and loops through each row and inserts extra column based on the position specified.

I'm checking if the column's value is empty then I'm inserting an `<TD>` which is an extra column.

**Problem :** Even though There is value in the next column in the code line

`var val = tColumns[iCol + 1].innerHTML;`, ITs throwing Null exception . Whats wrong with the code?

[image]

Comment: Pretty obvious from the error message: `tColumns[iCol + 1]` doesn't exist. Since you're iterating over a NodeList, you can't do `iCol + 1` when you're looking at the last element.

Comment: Well.. `tColumns[iCol + 1]` is undefined. Use `console.log` to see it or the debugger to watch it, check the values of `iCol` too. As it currently stands this question is very specific.

Comment: Anthony Gris - `tColumns[iCol + 1]` does exists.. It's declared much before the for loop!

Comment: Also see the output window, where I'm getting the value of ` tColumns[iCol + 1]`

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating over one more than the available length of the array.

I'm guessing you want to reference the *next* column. In which case change your for loop to this:

`for(var iCol = 0; iCol < t.Columns.length -1; iCol++)`